# How to use git blame in GitPython?

Tags: python, gitpython

I'm trying to use the GitPython module in my script... and I can't. That's not very documented : [GitPython Blame](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.blame)

I think I'm not so far, because the normally git blame I want to reproduce is the follow : `git blame -L127,+1 ../../core/src/filepath.cpp -e`

Here is my script :

```
from git import *
    repo = Repo("C:\\Path\\to\\my\\repos\\")
    assert not repo.bare
    # log_line = open("lineDeb.txt")
    # for line in log_line:
    repo.git.blame(L='127,+1' '../../core/src/filepath.cpp', e=True)
```

The two lines commented are for the final goal to git blame on each number line in my "lineDeb.txt" file.

I've the following ouput :

```
...
git.exc.GitCommandError: 'git blame -L127,+1../../core/src/filepath.cpp -e' returned with exit code 129
stderr: 'usage: git blame [options] [rev-opts] [rev] [--] file
...
```

The goal is to get the email of the line committer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for commit, lines in repo.blame('HEAD', filepath):
    print("%s changed these lines: %s" % (commit, lines))
```

The `commit` is the one that changed the given `lines`, in order of appearance in the file. Thus, if your would write all `lines` into a file, your would have the file at `filepath` at revision `HEAD`.

If you are looking for only a specific line, and as there are no options that you could currently pass to the `blame` subcommand, you would have to count to the line yourself.

```
ln = 127 # lines start at 0 here
tlc = 0

for commit, lines in repo.blame('HEAD', filepath):
    if tlc <= ln < (tlc + len(lines)):
         print(commit)
    tlc += len(lines)
```

This is less optimal than passing the respective `-L` option to `git blame`, but should do the job.

If it turns out to be too slow, you could consider making a PR that adds `**kwargs` to `Repo.blame` to pass on to `git blame`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've seen this command `repo.blame('HEAD', filepath)` but how I can blame only on specific line (127 for example) and get the email of the commiter ?

Comment: Python doesn't take the return commit... outside function. But just with print, that's work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're blaming a large number of lines you might find this higher performance:

```
blame = []
cmd = 'cd {path};git blame {fname}'.format(
            path=repo_path,
            fname=rootpath + fname)
with os.popen(cmd) as process:
   blame = process.readlines()

print blame[line_number]
```